# Java Regex - More efficient dynamic regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a Regex that I rely on for replacing variables in a string. The Regex itself works marvelously. I am more troubled by the efficiency of the Regex compilation. Based on profiling, my program spends a lot of time compiling this Regex, so perhaps there is a better mechanism for what I am trying to do. My code looks a bit like this:

```
for(String attribute : attributes.keySet())
{
  for(String searchAttribute : searchAttributes.keySet())
  {
    attributes.put(attributes.get(attribute).replaceAll(
    "(?<![A-Za-z0-9])"+searchAttribute+"(?![A-Za-z0-9])", 
    "(" + searchAttributes.get(searchAttribute) + ")");
  }
}
```

`attributes` and `searchAttributes` are HashMap. The values within them are assumed to be different on each call to the surrounding function. That is to say I cannot statically pre-compile the Regex once for the sets and be done.

This example is a tad contrived, but but it is very close to what I'm actually doing in my program. Is there a faster/better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Is `searchAttributes.keySet()` fixed or is it a parameter?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not sure I understand. In this example `attributes` and `searchAttributes` are HashMap<String, String>.

Comment: well, maybe put that in the question. But still - what populates that `HashMap` - is it "fixed", or is it different each time?

Comment: Can you simply look for occurrences of `searchAttribute`, and then do the look behind/look ahead "manually"?

Comment: Try word boundaries instead: `"\\b" + searchAttribute + "\\b"`

Comment: @AndyTurner I updated the question to reflect my comment. It seems like you were driving towards pre-compiling the regex, which would be fine, assuming the sets were constant, which they are not.

Comment: @anubhava Good thought, that may speed things along a little bit.